# How to know how many times an item have been repeated in an array in firebase flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose I have an array in firebase having the numbers `1,2,3,4,1,2,1,3,1,1,3` where `1` have been repeated multiple times , what I want is instead of presenting all the items in the array in my application convert the repeating items to number of times they have been repeated . For example here `1` have been repeated `5` times.

Is ther a way I can achieve this in flutter and firebase ?

Comment: Sounds feasible. Did you try anything already?

Comment: sir, I tried the best i could before asking here. But my knowledge is very limited , any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @basudevnayak, this sure is something that can be easily lookedup online. Have you tried searching there?

Comment: @JoyTerence I found some solution but most of them were for C++ , none were for firebase and especially flutter . so, thought this question might be worth asking.

Comment: Your question should include the [minimal, complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you wrote in an attempt to solve the problem, then explain what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson it's for my e-commerce application  which has very big and leanthy code, I am adding the product as an array to firease when added to cart , I want to show quantity based on repetation on the item in the array . The code would be too big to be posted here.

Comment: @basudevnayak, I checked and got many map based approach which seems to be appropriate solution to this, irrespective of the language. Would recommend you to check about maps in dart.

Comment: @JoyTerence Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want dart code that would give you output such as

> [[1, 5], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 1]]

then you can use the following code :

```
void main() {
List<int> og = [1,2,3,4,1,2,1,3,1,1,3];
print(og.toSet().toList().map((val){
  return [val, og.where((ogval)=>ogval==val).toList().length];
}).toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: Is this the answer you expected? Or do you expect different output?

Comment: It's kind of similar to what I was looking for

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I was lookig for a solution to implemt quantity option in my flutter e-commerce application. I have implemented a function which saves the id of the product in an array when the user add the product to cart, when the user wants to add the same product multiple times then the product is showing twice. To solve this I am planning to convert the repeating id to the number of times they have been repeated so , Instead of showing the produt twice or thrice I can show the quantity by calculating the number of times the ID have been repeated in the array in firebase.

Comment: So what I gave was correct its a list of [[product_id, quantity], [product_id, quantity]]. I think would have been ok to accept my answer if it solved your problem. Further this code can give you the quality for given product og.where((ogval)=>ogval==PRODUCT_ID).toList().length;

Comment: thank you so much , your answer made my day... with minor modification I obtained the functionality I was looking for ... I can't thank you more!!!